# Increase the maximum file size for ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

So I have a web API using the current version of ASP.NET Core, that has a image uploaded to it from an external site. By default, the server will only accept an image if the file size is below 1 MB otherwise it returns a 413 status code. How would I go about configuring the server/controller to allow a larger file?

Comment: Perhaps this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437282/dealing-with-large-file-uploads-on-asp-net-core-1-0?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't in the configuration of the ASP.NET server but was actually related to Ngixn and I had to modify the config file for that.