# Stream multipart request body without waiting for it to upload first

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is it possible to send a POST request to a controller and read the `HttpContext.Request.Body` stream immediately after sending the POST request (for example if the file is 10GB large)? If I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and a controller like this:

```
public class FileController : ControllerBase 
{
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task Upload() 
    {
        var stream = HttpContext.Request.Body;
    }
}
```

If I submit a file, it uploads the file first (as I can see in my browser), and then it hits the controller afterwards, with the whole file saved in a temporary file, as you can see here: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/07d115400e4f8c7a66ba239f230805f03a14ee3d/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities/FileBufferingReadStream.cs#L186

I can verify that it saves the uploaded file to disk, which won't work for my application, as I don't have unlimited storage. My end goal is to upload the file to FTP, so the request goes like this:

```
client -> service -> FTP
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437282/dealing-with-large-file-uploads-on-asp-net-core-1-0. Seems like you could read MultipartSection stream and direct the content toward FTP service.

Comment: @KirylZ I actually already use MultipartReader and so on, but the problem is that the code isn't being hit in my controller before after upload is done.

Comment: You mean before temp file is created on server side? Have u tried to remove default binders?

Comment: Like in here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming

Comment: @KirylZ Sorry for the late reply. That actually worked. If you want to answer so I can select it as the answer, go ahead!

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A range of solutions is described at [Dealing with large file uploads on ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437282/dealing-with-large-file-uploads-on-asp-net-core-1-0).

There is one important thing though that is not mentioned there - you have to remove the default binders. Otherwise buffering will kick in. Here is is how - [Upload large files with streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming).

Comment: Thanks again - it worked perfectly. I need to do a bit of hacking to get it to work, because of this line `Since model binding doesn't read the form, parameters that are bound from the form don't bind (query, route, and header continue to work)`. Meaning I cannot pass in any POST parameters or form data. I've added my necessary stuff in the header instead, which works flawlessly, but is kind of a hack.

Comment: So u're trying to pass several parameters in a request? Like the file and something else?

Comment: Basically, yeah. File is one of them and the path where to save the file is the other one. I had  to add an `X-Upload-Path` header along with the request to pass that with it. The second I start doing anything like `HttpContext.Request.Form` it will load the entire uploaded file into memory or on disk

Comment: I would suggest to pass all the parameters in a body and divide them with boundary and Content-Disposition header. Then you'll get them separately as Sections by calling MultipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync().

Comment: Yeah that would definitely be a good option as well. However, I only need the path so I can't be too bothered by it